# kth smallest element of an array, median of medians not fulfilling required time complexity

Tags: c++

I am trying to submit a solution to finding kth smallest element of an array to an online judge.
I picked up the most efficient fast algorithm, but the online judge still throws a time limit error. Is there a more faster algorithm?

It is an algorithm named Median of medians.
Code submitted:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
//#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int partition(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
    // Search for x in arr[l..r] and move it to end 
    int i;
    for (i = l; i < r; i++)
        if (arr[i] == x)
            break;
    swap(arr[i], arr[r]);

    // Standard partition algorithm 
    i = l;
    for (int j = l; j <= r - 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] <= x)
        {
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr[i], arr[r]);
    return i;
}

// A simple function to find median of arr[].  This is called 
// only for an array of size 5 in this program. 
int findMedian(int arr[], int n)
{
    sort(arr, arr + n);  // Sort the array 
    return arr[n / 2];   // Return middle element 
}

int kthSmallest(int arr[], int l, int r, int k)
{

    if (k > 0 && k <= r - l + 1)
    {
        int i, n = r - l + 1;
        int *median = new int[(n + 4) / 5];
        for (i = 0; i < n / 5; i++) {
            median[i] = findMedian(arr + l + i * 5, 5);
        }
        if (i * 5 < n) //For last group with less than 5 elements 
        {
            median[i] = findMedian(arr + l + i * 5, n % 5);
            i++;
        }
        int medOfMed = (i == 1) ? median[i - 1] :
            kthSmallest(median, 0, i - 1, i / 2);
        int pos = partition(arr, l, r, medOfMed);
        if (pos - l == k - 1)
            return arr[pos];
        if (pos - l > k - 1)
            return kthSmallest(arr, l, pos - 1, k);
        return kthSmallest(arr, pos + 1, r, k - pos + l - 1);
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}

// It searches for x in arr[l..r], and partitions the array  
// around x. 

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    int *a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    cout << kthSmallest(a, 0, n - 1, k);
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

If you know of a more efficient algorithm than this one, or an idea to improve this one, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Side question: I've been seeing `freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);` a lot latelyand it's screwed up a few. What do they gain from messing with `cin` and `cout` that they wouldn't get from opening file streams the "normal" way?

Comment: FYI, There already is a `std::partition` algorithm function.  There is no need to write your own.

Answer (score -1):

There's a function std::nth_element in the `<algorithm>` header (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) which can be used to find median of an array fast.

Comment: I don't know which header. Please if you can tell me the name of the algorithm. I omitted sort, still time limit error.

Comment: sorry, the header is```#include <algorithm>```

Comment: and the algorithm's name is std::nth_element

Comment: I still do not get it, be precise if you want to help.

Comment: Well if you read the docs on said function, you will learn how to use it to determine what median of an array is fast. I don't really know how to apply that knowledge to the problem you're solving.

Comment: Ashley, with the added comments you've just about turned your non-answer into an answer. Might as well finish it off.

Comment: @AshleyWilkes Plus, I am not supposed to use any function except the standard sorting function. So, I am looking for actual algorithmic tricks.

Comment: The function can be used with arrays too. You asked if there was a faster algorithm, I answered that question. I can't read minds to see there are limitations to your choice that you don't bother to mention.